# Custom extended file attributes

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded-linux

I need to find a way to store information about certain resource file verification. The idea is to store it on file system as custom extended file attribute. Requirements:

- I need to store only bool - verified / not verified
- Only certain group members can change/add/remove this attribute
- If file is changed it should drop its verification attribute

Is it possible to do it that way? Can anybody share some links about extended attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I don't think that adding attributes is a feasible solution.

I would rely on an external file which contains these attributes for all your files.

Comment: We already have similar solution, but file parsing is too time consuming. The idea is to implement it as simple and as efficient as possible.